# unable to fetch wanted querie in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I've next data

```
id cid vid firstname lastname dtype dname createdat
1  32   34  ramesh    kjk       t    check 2021-11-02 10:00:51.66395
1  32   34  ramesh    kjk       t    check 2021-11-01 10:00:51.66395
1  32   4   raj       kjk       c    check 2021-11-04 10:00:51.66395
```

excepted o/p:

```
id cid vid firstname lastname dtype dname createdat
1  32   34  ramesh    kjk       t    check 2021-11-02 10:00:51.66395
1  32   4   raj       kjk       c    check 2021-11-04 10:00:51.66395
```

need to fetch only the only latest record of each user(vid) and document type can be c or t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use corelated subquery

```
  select t1.* from table_nam t1
    where t1.createdat=(select max(createdat) from table_nam t2 where t1.vid=t2.vid)
```

also you can use distinct on

```
select distinct on (vid) as vid,createdat,cid
from table_name
order by vid,createdat desc
```

Comment: @sainithin mark it accepted

Comment: if i want put a filter in the above query (as optional) where dtype is t
i need only documents with t ?